# IIS Website not working?

Tags: iis

I have recently installed IIS on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Domain Controller.
If I type localhost on Google Chrome I get the welcome page. I created a simple test webpage and saved the file in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` folder.
In binding I assigned the only IP address I have (static). Port is 5959. In hostname I am using "www.mysite.com".:

The problem is when I try to run the site from Google Chrome I get the error: "No Internet Connection". I created a new site with no hostname, ip address unassigned. I can access this new site with `192.168.1.1"5959`

Comment: I would not run a web server from your domain controller o([|||||||||])::;;::;;::;;::;;::;;> STAB

Answer (score 0):

Ports are defined with a `:` not an `=`

```
192.168.1.1:5959
```

Comment: that is a typo in my question. I did specify 192.168.1.1:595, but it still did not work!